# How do I find a personal message which is sent by moderator to me a few months back?

Tags: support

A few months back, a moderator sent me a private message (I don't know that word is correct, I mean sometimes SO users may use another name instead of private message.)

Now I wanted read it again. How I find it?

Comment: Do you mean a conversation in a separate chat room?

Comment: @SurajRao No. He sent me a message about my ban.  I was blocked for 7 days. He said the reason for it using a message. I need to find it.

Comment: Have you looked into your site inbox? Scroll back a bit if necessary until you find something that says something similar to "message from moderator"... ?

Comment: @JonClements Seems like it is really hard. There are lots of item. I don't remember the extract month also. There are lots of items too (38 pages). As I know there is no search function for inbox.... If there is I can search because I remember some words to search.

Comment: August 23rd... if you can't find it, I can provide you a link which only you can access - but have a look first.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. I will try to find. Thanks for sending me the date

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. I found it. How do you find the date?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson He is a mod, he can easily find this stuff from the Mod panel.